# i must add CausesValidation="False" to every ASP Button to work, why?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Hello i have a Big ASP Page and i must set in every ASP Button this:

```
CausesValidation="False"
```

to work. If don't it cant run a codebehind function.

can somebody explain to me why this is so?

Comment: Do you have a validator control in your page? If so, do you use ValidationGroups?

Comment: There must me validators on your page that are failing which is stopping the control to run a code behind function. you need to search the validator which is failing and do the needful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are using Validation controls in your page. Your page must pass the validation before postback to server. Below is the functionality of CausesValidation property:

- The CausesValidation property specifies if a page is validated when a
  Button control is clicked.
- Page validation is performed when a button is clicked by default.
- This property is mostly used to prevent validation when a cancel or reset button is clicked.

Comment: Something like this: <asp:RequiredFieldValidator" ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb1" ValidationGroup="ValidateMe" />

Comment: yes i found some requiredfieldvalidatior. should i group them to prevent the causesvalidation to every asp button?